# Azure Access Package direct assignment with approval

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In the Azure Portal, I can navigate to **Identity Governance | Access Packages | Access Package** and then create a direct assignment for a user. The Azure Portal allows me to specify whether or not approvals are applied to the assignment request.

[image: Azure Portal Access Package Direct Assignment Screenshot]

I can also create a direct assignment request using the Microsoft Graph, but I cannot figure out how to apply approvals to this request. Requests from the Graph seem to always bypass the approval policy.

Using Fiddler and the Azure Portal (ref screenshot above), I can see that the following JSON payload is POSTed to the Graph. So I took that exact same JSON payload and POSTed it with the Graph Explorer, but the approval process is still being bypassed.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identityGovernance/entitlementManagement/accessPackageAssignmentRequests

{
    "accessPackageAssignment": {
        "target": {
            "objectId": "5eaf3cdc-3859-40a1-bd48-583da94d16b3",
            "type": "User"
        },
        "assignmentPolicyId": "3261eff8-1e91-426d-93dd-55f196a593a4",
        "accessPackageId": "d14d6f8c-458f-4a1c-926a-38f4c5e63fe8"
    },
    "justification": "testing",
    "requestType": "AdminAdd",
    "parameters": [
        {
            "name": "IsApprovalRequired",
            "value": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve the same behavior as the Azure Portal (i.e., direct access package assignment with approval)?

Comment: I just discovered that posting the JSON noted above to http://elm.iga.azure.com does indeed create an access package request and approvals are properly applied, but I'm pretty sure it would be a bad idea to depend on that endpoint

Comment: Have you found a solution, I am also struggling to make this work and have done the same debugging as you?

Comment: Negative and as far as I know there is currently no work around. :/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I also tried using fiddler to debug the incoherent results I had from Graph Api, mgGraph cmdlets and elm.iga.azure.com. Seing your response made me accept that I wasn't the problem. Using beta/preview functionalities come with a risk.. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In the [request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/entitlementmanagement-post-accesspackageassignmentrequests?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request-body), it contains a `accessPackageAssignmentRequest` object which has a property `assignmentPolicyId`, and the `assignmentPolicyId` property identifying the [accessPackageAssignmentPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/entitlementmanagement-post-accesspackageassignmentpolicies?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), and this policy has a definition for `requestApprovalSettings`. [approvalSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approvalsettings?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) contained `isApprovalRequired`.

[image]

By the way, what you mentioned are `beta` version api which is not recommended. And [V1.0 version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/entitlementmanagement-post-assignmentpolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) may be better.

Comment: Tiny, the access package assignment policy is already configured to require approvals, but accessPackageAssignmentRequest with a request type of **AdminAdd** are bypassing the approval and are being immediately delivered to the target user. Here is a gist to my policy object. https://gist.github.com/hazlettp/4994ec973b8766992686c9bd693786fe